# Android PlaceFilter usage with Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I am trying to use the Google Places API and I would like to filter my search to only gym types.

I am using the code given at https://developers.google.com/places/

```
public void onPickButtonClick(View v) {
// Construct an intent for the place picker
try {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
        new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
    // Start the intent by requesting a result,
    // identified by a request code.
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);

} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // ...
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // ...
}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
    int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER
    && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

    // The user has selected a place. Extract the name and address.
    final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

    final CharSequence name = place.getName();
    final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
    String attributions = PlacePicker.getAttributions(data);
    if (attributions == null) {
        attributions = "";
    }

    mViewName.setText(name);
    mViewAddress.setText(address);
    mViewAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));

} else {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

What I was trying to do was to create a filter like below and somehow add that (placeFilter) to the intent.

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
PlaceFilter placeFilter;
ArrayList<String> restictToGyms = new ArrayList<>();
restictToGyms.add("44");
placeFilter = new PlaceFilter(false, restictToGyms);
intent.SOMEHOWADD(placeFilter);
Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
```

But I am not sure how to add this filter to the intent. In fact I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is currently an open feature request for it :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826944
Feel free to 'star' it maybe it could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking to do the same thing.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible-  the PlaceFilter takes place ids, not types.  The class PlaceFilter is final so it cannot be extended (I hate it when API writers make classes final, there's almost never a reason to do it).  You need to actually make the call and do the filtering via a loop after the result returns.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html

Gym is Place.TYPE_GYM

Comment: I have already looked into that link. In fact, that's how I got the restictToGyms.add("44"); because Place.TYPE_GYM is 44. What I need is how to add this to the intent so that google maps only returns the TYPE_GYM results.