# Google Places API Android filter according to place type

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to filter nearby places specifically hospitals. I'm using Google Places API for Android. My code below doesn't have any errors, but it doesn't show any hospitals.

```
List<String> filters = new ArrayList<>();
filters.add(String.valueOf(Place.TYPE_HOSPITAL));
PlaceFilter placeFilter = new PlaceFilter(false, filters);

PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, placeFilter);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng())
                            .title((String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName())
                            .snippet((String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPhoneNumber()));
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have a look at this link hope it helps,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34057884/5722385

Comment: @Mrinmoy I'm using Google Places API for Android

Comment: Ya I saw, that is what I was going to ask, is it possible for you to change it the way that link suggest

Comment: @Mrinmoy No, I need to do it that way

Comment: I searched a lot but no clue yet, some one said its not possible, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/35425437/5722385

Comment: It looks like there is a feature request in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829588. Add a star to express your interest.

Comment: well... it still the same. Btw, the PlacePicker also does not have filtering, so not so usefull at all.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPlaceTypes()` and then use a for loop and search for the specific number of a category 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html?hl=es-419#TYPE_RESTAURANT

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer. Here is an example of a loop that brings back places of type "RESTAURANT". It uses the place likelihood methods described in [https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details#get-place]

```
//Looping through each placeLikelihood objects.
for(PlaceLikelihood placelikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods){
    //Convert the place types obtaines from Place Likelihood into an array so that we can loop through
    Object[] typeOfPlace = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes().toArray();
    for(Object placeType : typeOfPlace){
       if(placeType.toString().equals("RESTAURANT")){
           Timber.i("Place is %s", placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName);
       }        
    }   
}
```

With that in mind, I think this would be helpful for you.

```
for(PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces){
    Object[] typeOfPlace = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes().toArray();
    for(Object placeType : typeOfPlace){
            if(placeType.toString().equals("HOSPITAL")){
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng())
                        .title((String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName())
                        .snippet((String) 
                         placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPhoneNumber()));

            }
    }

}
```